# Is it possible to configure what is shown in control center

Tags: iphone, ios

I like the new control center in iOS7.

I would like to know if there is possible to set up what should be available in it? 
One thing is which toggle settings to show at the top row, like turn on/off mobile data (not flight mode, as I want to be able to call and receive calls).
Another thing is to specify which apps to be accessible at the bottom row.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment : nope, it's not configurable.